# Select all column except one column in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to exclude count to remove duplicates in below query

```
SELECT *, count(1) as count except (count)
  FROM PRD.sites  
  group by site,id ,site_desc,timestamp
  having count(1) < 2
```

but got error Unexpected keyword EXCEPT at [1:29].
I am using standardSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to include COUNT() into SELECT list - below will perfectly work and will remove duplicate rows based on fields enlisted

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(t)
FROM PRD.sites t 
group by site,id ,site_desc,timestamp
having count(1) < 2
```

Above will show only rows which do not have dups (based on fields in group by)

If you rather need to remove dups based on fields - use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(t)
FROM PRD.sites t 
group by site,id ,site_desc,timestamp
```

If you need to de-dup based on whole row - you can use below

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM PRD.sites
```

Comment: Why are you using `select as value` for this?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - otherwise it will output all fields as a STRUCT

Comment: @NikhilBOORLA - sure, consider also voting up the answer if it helped

Answer (score 6):

You can try below

```
select * except(count)
from
(
  SELECT *, count(1) as count 
  FROM PRD.sites  
  group by site,id ,site_desc,timestamp
  having count(1) < 2
)X
```

OR You can use row_number() for finding duplicates

```
SELECT * except(rn)
FROM (
  SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER()
          OVER (PARTITION BY site,id ,site_desc,timestamp) as rn
  FROM FROM PRD.sites
)
WHERE rn= 1
```

Comment: Thanks!!!but i have around 20 columns in table other than site,id,site_desc,timestamp.Do i need to include all columns in group by clause?

Comment: yes, you need to include all in group by @NikhilBOORLA

Comment: @NikhilBOORLA, you can use window function row_number() for finding duplicates too

Answer (score 1):

You can try with temp table

```
/* Get the data into a temp table */
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM YourTable
/* Drop the columns that are not needed */
ALTER TABLE #TempTable
DROP COLUMN ColumnToDrop
/* Get results and drop temp table */
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```